# anaconda tensorflow ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I try use tensorflow first time.

I installed Anaconda, CUDA, cudnn, pytorch and tensorflow.

I set cudnn path like below, too.

```
C:\cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32\cuda\bin
C:\cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32\cuda\lib
C:\cudnn-10.2-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32\cuda\include
```

And I try start python project  import tensorflow.
But that occurred error.
I'll write error message below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: cannot find module for path

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./trainplate.py", line 4, in <module>
    from utils.logger import *
  File "C:\machine_learning\PyTorch-YOLOv3-master\utils\logger.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\blue_\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: cannot find module for path


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

How can I fix this error?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

I downgraded tensorflow version to 2.0. Then, tensorflow error was gone.